# Child properties of Schema.org property

Tags: seo, semantic-web, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I've been trying to figure out this riddle from a day now.
Lets say that we have a TV Episode as following,

```
<main itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/TVEpisode">
    <h1>
      <a itemprop="url" href="self.html">
          Pokemon - <span itemprop="episodeNumber">88</span>
      </a>
    </h1>
    <h2 itemprop="name">In the Pink</h2>
    <p>Source: <span itemprop="partOfSeries">Pokemon</span>
               <span itemprop="partOfSeason">Orange Islands</span>
    </p>
</main>
```

Now the problem here is that I'm unable to add the 'sameAs' property of 'partOfSeries' here. If I add an anchor with 'sameAs' property inside 'partOfSeries', Google Structured-data Testing Tool says it cant find the sameAs property. And I don't know anyway else to do it. The same is correct for 'seasonNumber' which is a child of 'partOfSeason'.
If you could help out with the 'potentialAction' property too, that would be awesome.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`partOfSeason` property](http://schema.org/partOfSeason) expects a value of the [`Season` type](http://schema.org/Season).
The [`partOfSeries` property](http://schema.org/partOfSeries) expects a value of the [`Series` type](http://schema.org/Series).
You are giving a text value in both cases.

This is [not *wrong*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571729/1591669) (just not recommended), but with a text value it’s not possible to give additional data about the season/series.

In the Microdata syntax, you’d have to create a new *item* with the `itemscope` attribute and give its type with the `itemtype` attribute:

```html
<span itemprop="partOfSeries" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Series">
  <span itemprop="name">Pokemon</span>
</span>

<span itemprop="partOfSeason" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Season">
  <span itemprop="name">Orange Islands</span>
</span>
```

(Because simple text inside of an item is not considered to be a Microdata value, you have to use a property for everything you want to associate with the item, i.e, Schema.org’s `name` in this case.)

Now you can add additional properties that only apply to their parents (`Series`/`Season`), not to the `TVEpisode`:

```html
<span itemprop="partOfSeries" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Series">
  <span itemprop="name">Pokemon</span>
  <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_%28anime%29"/>
</span>

<span itemprop="partOfSeason" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Season">
  <span itemprop="name">Orange Islands</span>
  <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon:_Adventures_on_the_Orange_Islands_episodes"/>
</span>
```

---

Side notes about your example:

- You are using Schema.org URLs with the `https` protocol. Not wrong, but [I recommend to always use `http`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112323/1591669).
- You should not use an additional heading element for an alternative heading (`h2` in your case); you could use `p` instead, and group the heading with the alternative title in a `header` (see HTML5’s [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/common-idioms.html#sub-head)).