# Schema Markup: How to temporarily "escape" itemscope

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I would like to markup some content using Schema but am running into an issue with my itemscopes.

I have the following markup right now:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/medicalClinic">
  <div itemprop="availableService" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/MedicalProcedure">
    <span itemprop="name">First Service Name</span>
    <span itemprop="description">First Service Description</span>
    <div itemprop="availableService itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/MedicalProcedure">
      <span itemprop="name">Second Service Name</span>
      <span itemprop="description">Second Service Description</span>
    </div><!-- end second service -->
    <span itemprop="followup">First Service Followup</span>
  </div><!-- end first service -->
</div><!-- end MedicalClinic schema -->
```

Due to the way the content is structured, a second service appears in the middle of the container for the first service. Itemprops for the first service appear before and after the second service.

[Google's structured data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) shows an error stating that an availableService is not a property of an availableService (obviously not what I would want anyway).

My question is **how do I "escape" the scope of my first service** so I am able to markup my second service, and then re-enter the first service's scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s an ugly solution for this which involves adding a `div` with an `itemscope` (without `itemtype`) and `itemref`+`id`:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalClinic" itemref="second-service">

  <div itemprop="availableService" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalProcedure">
    <span itemprop="name">First Service Name</span>
    <span itemprop="description">First Service Description</span>

    <div itemscope>

      <div itemprop="availableService" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalProcedure" id="second-service">
        <span itemprop="name">Second Service Name</span>
        <span itemprop="description">Second Service Description</span>
      </div><!-- end second service -->

    </div> <!-- end dummy div -->

    <span itemprop="followup">First Service Followup</span>
  </div><!-- end first service -->

</div><!-- end MedicalClinic schema -->
```

Notes about your markup:

- you may want to [use HTTP instead of HTTPS Schema.org URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112323/1591669)
- Schema.org URIs are case-sensitive (e.g., it’s `http://schema.org/MedicalClinic`, not `http://schema.org/medicalClinic`)
- you were missing an `itemprop`’s closing `"`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I also fixed a few errors and am following your advice on using HTTP URI's. Much appreciated!